# Mysql Join - Filter results based on two max values

Tags: mysql

I am having the following data set:

```
+----+------------+------+-------+----------+
| id |    date    | week | time  |  price   |
+----+------------+------+-------+----------+
|  1 | 2015-05-01 |   24 | 13:25 | 1.251325 |
|  2 | 2015-05-01 |   24 | 14:25 | 1.251256 |
|  3 | 2015-05-02 |   24 | 15:25 | 1.251715 |
|  4 | 2015-05-02 |   24 | 16:25 | 1.251588 |
|  5 | 2015-05-10 |   25 | 17:25 | 1.251347 |
+----+------------+------+-------+----------+
```

I used the following code to get the latest price at the end of each day, which delivers perfect results:

```
SELECT t.id, t.date, t.time, t.balance
FROM db1 t JOIN
(SELECT tt.date, MAX(tt.time) as 'maxtime'
FROM db1 tt
GROUP BY tt.date
) m
ON m.maxtime = t.time AND t.date = m.date;
```

However, now I would also like to have a query delivering the latest price of each week. Hence, I would need to look for the latest date within each week and then for the maximum time. I tried something like this, but this is clearly not the right syntax:

```
SELECT t.id, t.date, t.time, t.balance
FROM db1 t JOIN
(SELECT tt.date, MAX(tt.time) as 'maxtime'
FROM db1 tt
GROUP BY tt.date
AND 
SELECT tt.week, MAX(tt.date) as 'maxdate'
FROM db1 tt
GROUP BY tt.week
) m
ON m.maxtime = t.time AND m.week = t.week AND m.maxdate = t.date;
```

The question is how I can link the two conditions based on two different "Group by". The result I am looking for should look like that:

```
+----+------------+------+-------+----------+
| id |    date    | week | time  |  price   |
+----+------------+------+-------+----------+
|  4 | 2015-05-02 |   24 | 16:25 | 1.251588 |
|  5 | 2015-05-10 |   25 | 17:25 | 1.251347 |
+----+------------+------+-------+----------+
```

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Comment: As a recommendation, MySQL has a `DATETIME` object you can use to avoid having two separate columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is strange to see that you have separate columns for date and time, but maybe this is necessary to store repeated times (11:00 daily) or dates without times. Otherwise you should use a datetime instead.

What you are looking for is the latest datetime or timestamp in a week. You get this when you combine date and time.

```
SELECT t.id, t.date, t.time, t.balance
FROM db1 t JOIN
(SELECT tt.week, MAX(timestamp(tt.date,tt.time)) as 'maxtime'
FROM db1 tt
GROUP BY tt.week
) m
ON m.maxtime = timestamp(t.date,t.time) AND t.week = m.week;
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of the `timestamp()` function. This looks a bit cleaner than my string concatenation.

Answer (score 2):

What I recommend doing, if it's not an option to combine your date and time objects into one `DATETIME` column, is first research the [`TIMESTAMP()`](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-timestamp-function.php) function which can be used to convert both columns into one datetime object like this:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP(dateColumn, timeColumn) AS fullDate
FROM myTable;
```

Once you have that, you can write a query to get the max DateTime for each week, and join back to your original table to get all values like this:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM myTable m
JOIN(
  SELECT week, MAX(TIMESTAMP(dateColumn, timeColumn)) AS latestDate
  FROM myTable
  GROUP BY week) mt ON mt.week = m.week AND mt.latestDate = TIMESTAMP(m.datecolumn, m.timecolumn);
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/af498/3) example.

Answer (score 1):

You could concatenate the date and time into one value and apply max on that like this:

```
SELECT t.id, t.date, t.week, t.time, t.price
FROM db1 t 
JOIN (
  SELECT tt.week, MAX(concat(tt.date, ' ', tt.time)) as 'maxtime'
  FROM db1 tt
  GROUP BY tt.week
) m ON m.maxtime = concat(t.date, ' ', t.time) and t.week = m.week;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/daf21/5)